# how to stop egress traffic in gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have been facing problem about huge cost consumption due to egress traffic in gcp. we Run around 250-400 preemptible instances to save cost.But egress traffic is costing us in lakhs. how to prevent this, please explain the ways to stop it. If it requires some kind of debugging then share the debugging steps as well.

Comment: "costing us in lakhs" is probably really unclear to most people, because that's an Indian measurement. If you want to have some sort of value there, please use f. ex. US dollars (and non-indian measurements).

Answer (score 0):

If your egress traffic is due to legitimate customers accessing your servers, you can not just reduce it by cutting traffic off (e.g firewall rules), but you may check if this [document](https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/pricing) about premium tier and standard tier traffic pricing is useful, and which should be implemented in January.

However, if the egress traffic is not legit (e.g due to DDOS attacks), you may check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/files/GCPDDoSprotection-04122016.pdf) for best practices, and you may check if [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/) would be useful for your use case.

But, to control egress traffic in general, that is per your application design. Thus the question is broad and hard to answer as it is not addressing a specific technical issue with a certain product.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions and recommendations ,But in my case suppose my vm are in us region (asume any) but the services are being used by indian users only .will the egress cost be applicable in this case ??

Comment: As this is a different question I encourage you to click the ask button , and I will be happy to post an answer . But the short answer is yes. And that is applicable to customers accessing your servers from the internet even if your customers are in Iowa, USA area or not. Internet Egress pricing is applicable for any traffic leaving the GCP network (using an external IP) except if the destination is a Google cloud service or Google product (Youtube, Maps, Drive, etc). Free egress is applicable only when using internal IP addresses (internally within the GCP network) in the same zone.

Comment: it means i will be charged on equally regardless of the fact my servers are in us-central or india .Because in documentation we have seen there are price difference per vcpu depending in which region you are running your servers .

Comment: As to clarify my last comment, I meant internet Egress traffic costs and not all costs.  correcting my statement: in your case and if your customers are in India it should not make any difference in terms of Internet Egress price if your servers are in us-central or in asia-south1, and according to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#network). But rather your customers will encounter a higher latency assuming they are in the Mumbai area and your servers are in us-central.